# How to put 6 images in columns of 3

Tags: css

I want to put 6 images in total but it should show up as 3 images per column and the columns should be centered and beside each other.

Here is my code, but using flex box breaks the page. How do I do this?

```css
.gallery img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 20rem;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <h1>Gallery</h1>
  <img src="images/gallery1.jpg" alt="gallery-pic1">
  <img src="images/gallery2.jpg" alt="gallery-pic2">
  <img src="images/gallery3.jpg" alt="gallery-pic3">
  <img src="images/gallery4.jpg" alt="gallery-pic4">
  <img src="images/gallery5.jpg" alt="gallery-pic5">
  <img src="images/gallery6.jpg" alt="gallery-pic6">
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a picture of what is expected?

Comment: Flex wrap is set to nowrap by default, set it to wrap and make sure your items has the right width

Comment: "breaks the page" is not the greatest error description. Please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use flex

`display: flex` need to be set on the container of the images so that the images becomes flex items. The container is where you set `justify-content` and not on the items themselves unless your items are also display flex with children in them

Finally, `flex-wrap` which is default to `nowrap` need to be set to `wrap` so everything will wrap when proper. Then it's just a matter of adding in some width. Your gallery title I set it to 100% width and each image is set to 30% width. justify content I set it to `space-between` so that it looks nice.

This is just an example, adjust how you see fit

I suggest you read this guide as it is very easy to understand

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.gallery img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 20rem;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
h1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <h1>Gallery</h1>
  <img src="images/gallery1.jpg" alt="gallery-pic1">
  <img src="images/gallery2.jpg" alt="gallery-pic2">
  <img src="images/gallery3.jpg" alt="gallery-pic3">
  <img src="images/gallery4.jpg" alt="gallery-pic4">
  <img src="images/gallery5.jpg" alt="gallery-pic5">
  <img src="images/gallery6.jpg" alt="gallery-pic6">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox on the outer container, and grid on an inner container that just holds the images.

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery .grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <h1>Gallery</h1>
  <div class="grid">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="gallery-pic1">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="gallery-pic2">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="gallery-pic3">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="gallery-pic4">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="gallery-pic5">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="gallery-pic6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

from your code.

You can use flex, flex-wrap for the parent and width/min-width and flex-grow for the children:

example:

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 20rem;
  opacity: 0.6;
  gap:5px;
  background:#bee
}

.gallery h1 {
  min-width: 90%;
  margin:0;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 30%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <h1>Gallery</h1>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200&text=1.jpg" alt="gallery-pic1">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200&text=2.jpg" alt="gallery-pic2">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200&text=3.jpg" alt="gallery-pic3">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200&text=4.jpg" alt="gallery-pic4">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200&text=5.jpg" alt="gallery-pic5">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200&text=6.jpg" alt="gallery-pic6">
</div>
```